# $http.get reutrns source code instead of html results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I'm new to AngularJS. Using **$http** service, i'm requesting an HTML page from **localhost**. But i'm getting the source code of that page instead of the result.

**http_service.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJs | HTTP Service</title>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Initialize the Angular Application
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        // Initialize an Angular Controller
        app.controller('controller', function($scope, $http){
            // Ruquest a page from the remote server
            $http.get('files/myFile.html')
                // After initializing the $http object, run a succes function
                .then(function(response){
                    $scope.reqData = response.config;
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="controller">
    <h4>{{reqData}}</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

**files/myFile.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello from AngularJS by Google</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

how can i show the heading in **myFile.html** instead of the source code.

Comment: @MohammedSiyab: Do you mean to render the html file from server side or you just want to bind it to html?

Comment: use ng-src if looking for populating file from client side or can plug in as view also

Comment: What do you mean source code instead of HTML page, isn't source code a HTML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view

Comment: use `ng-bind-html`

Comment: @Muhammad Neswine: I want to bind it to to html

Comment: @maurycy:  recently, i learnt the concept of services in AngularJS. when using $http service, i tried to request some html from an external file but getting the problem mentioned above.And i mean it's showing me the source code of the html page not the result..

Answer (score 0):

can you try to assign the value by injecting $sce and use the code change as below,

```
$http.get('files/myFile.html').then(function(response){
     $scope.reqData = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.config);
});
```