# Viewing HTML string as HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, highlight

I have some autogenerated html code highlighting some texts in my angularJS app. The line generating the html code is this one:

```
var replaced = original.replace(regEx, '<span style="background-color: red;">' + replacing + '</span>');
line[key + 'HL'] = replaced;
```

But writing this on template

```
<div><p>{{line.codeHL ? line.codeHL : line.code}} {{line.price}}</p></div>
```

shows this:

```
<span style="background-color: red;">GD5AU211</span> 102€
```

How can I force the evaluation of html code inside a string?

Also let's just say I can't use `document.getElementById()` for reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this link. This may be what you seek: 
[AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view)

To enable html insertion into view you have to define html as trusted data using `$sce.trustAsHtml()`

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular 4 then use `innerHTML`

```
<div><p>

   <div [innerHTML]="line.codeHL ? line.codeHL : line.code">
    </div> {{line.price}}

</p></div>
```

if you are using angular 1 then use `ng-bing-html`

```
<div><p>
       <div ng-bind-html="line.codeHL ? line.codeHL : line.code | cust">
        </div> {{line.price}}
</p></div>
```

now create a `cust` filter like this

```
.filter('cust',function($sce){
  return function(html){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm on angular 1.4 :(

Comment: @Parantap Parashar solution worked so I assume yours would work too since it does basically the same.

Comment: @p4x yes it should

Answer (score 0):

Add `<xmp>` tag before your html that has to be displayed as text.

```
var replaced = original.replace(regEx, '<span style="background-color: red;"><xmp>' + replacing + '</xmp></span>');
```