# Passing in string into angular

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

In my function, I call an opening of a modal and the template of this modal is a PHP file. 
In that file, I have a div element which has the value of `{{msg_text}}`.

In my js file I set `$scope.msg_text` so that when the modal is opened, it shows the value that I set in the `js`.

This works fine but I am trying to add line **breaks/paragraphs** but it's just printing out the **text** instead of adding the spaces

How do I go about adding a **break** in between paragraphs by passing in a string?

Comment: The html is being escaped see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view

Answer (score 1):

pass the HTML as a string for ex:

```
var msg = "<p>My data</p></br><p>Next line</p>"
```

and in HTML use `ng-bind-html` attribute to render HTML string

```
<div ng-bind-html="msg_text"></div>
```

Use `$sce.trustAsHtml()` in the controller to convert the html string.

```
$scope.msg_text = $sce.trustAsHtml(msg);
```

Comment: This code will give the HTML unsafe error. VM535:27 Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.

Comment: I am currently getting $sce is not defined

Comment: pass `$sce` as a dependency in your controller

Answer (score 1):

You first need to add the line breaks `\n` in the value of your scope variable. lets say like this

```
$scope.msg_text = 'This is a sample text\n This is in a new line';
```

Then you simply need to use the `<pre>` tag to display your text as you needed

```
<pre>{{msg_text }}</pre>
```

Here is the link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/30wrat2x/1/) for more detail