# Insert html using angularjs between div tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I saw it was possible to insert HTML between div tags using innerHTML, example:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '<span
class="prego">Something</span>';
```

I'm working on a Angularjs projet and I tried something similar:

```
function insertTransmissionHTML(param){
        var transmission = 'transmission'+param;
        var partrans = 'partrans'+param;

        document.getElementById(partrans).innerHTML = '<form class="form-horizontal"><div ng-repeat="param in '+transmission+'"><label class="control-label">{{param.libelle}}</label><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="param.valeur"></div></form>';
    }
```

Then i call the function:

```
insertTransmissionHTML("FTP");
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="partransFTP" class="tab-pane fade">            
</div>
```

I use a $scope.transmissionFTP with some parameters and i should have something like that:

```
parameter 1
parameter 2
...
```

But I have:

```
 {{param.libelle}}
```

It looks like the angularjs here isn't working, it becomes a simple HTML.

EDIT:
Here is my example at the beginning (it works):

```
<div id="partransFTP" class="tab-pane fade">
  <form class="form-horizontal"> 
    <div ng-repeat="param in transmissionFTP">
      <label class="control-label">{{param.libelle}}</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="param.valeur">          
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And I had all my parameters (from $scope.transmissionFTP)

```
parameter 1
parameter 2
...
```

But I have to do something dynamically. Why is it showing {{param.libelle}} and not all my parameters when I use insertTransmissionHTML ?

Has some one a suggestion ?
Thank you a lot !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @LiverpoolOwen: I have to create dynamically some div. LucaDeNardi I'll try this but I don't know if it can solve my problem.

Comment: I edited my question, maybe it's more complete now !

Comment: You almost never want to inject HTML directly into the DOM when using Angular; the framework won't know about it, can't add bindings to it, and will blow it away on the next digest update.  Modify scope data and let Angular do the work of drawing it into the DOM.     In this case it looks like your form ought to be another Angular directive, or just include it in the current directive's template and `ng-show/hide` if necessary.

Comment: @DanielBeck I already thought about a show/hide div solution, but it will be less dynamic and if i'm looking for a dynamic solution it's because I can have a lot of div. But I'll go for that if I don't find something else. Thank you anyway !

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it will be less dynamic" here.  It can be as "dynamic" as anything else Angular does (which is to say, completely dynamic.  All the dynamic there is.)   This is how Angular is designed to work; if you try to bypass it you're just making more work for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm tad bit confused regarding your issue, but when I need to inject dynamic HTML I use the following directive:

```
   app.directive('dynamic', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function (html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

In my Angular controller I save the HTML string to a scope variable

```
var $scope.myScopeVariable = '<div>My HTML Goes HERE</div>';
```

, and in my html page, I use:

```
<div dynamic = "myScopeVariable">
```

Hopefully, this will help you.

Comment: I tried with an easy example it works fine. But I don't know why when I insert an id it doesnt work, example: $scope.myScoreVariable="<div id="test"></div>" when I use document.getElementById("test") having "null".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular **ngSanitize**, try something like the below example also check the sample [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vi138XKuKNpdRU1MJkiC) :

Template:

```
<span ng-bind-html="name">
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.name = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b>World</b>');
});
```

Comment: ng-bind-html won't be sufficient in this case, note that they're trying to inject other angular variables and directives (`{{param.libelle}}`, `ng-model`) as well as pure html...

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned, directly interacting with the DOM outside of the Angular digest cycle will produce cases where DOM elements aren't synched w/ Angular directives.

However, to answer your question, I would suggest using/looking into [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to force Angular to relink `$scope` and your template together. Try adding something like this to your function:

```
$compile(angular.element('div#partransFTP').contents())($scope);
```