# How can you add HTML markup in a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to add a small amount of HTML inside part of my Javascript array for the **synopsis**. Is there a method to do this as currently it outputs as text?

So far I have the below

```
app.controller('primaryServiceListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.serviceListings = [
        {
            url: "details.html",
            img: "service-01.jpg",
            sector: "Business",
            synopsis: "Completely synergize resource taxing relationships <strong>via premier niche markets</strong>. Professionally cultivate one-to-one customer service robust."
        }
    ]
}]);
```

Comment: 'currently it outputs as text' - what does this mean? Can you show the relevant html snippet where this is used?

Comment: I think best practice is that HTML should be in a Component, and your array should store names (or references) of Components, rather than the HTML.  If HTML is generated during run time, structure the Component that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view)

Comment: as text .. as in taxing relationships <strong>via premier niche markets</strong>

Answer (score 1):

You need to include [`ngSanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) in your app and then, in your template, you can bind the HTML easily using `ng-bind-html` directive:

```
<div ng-bind-html="serviceListings[0].synopsis"></div>
```

Please see the following working demo:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.serviceListings = [{
      url: "details.html",
      img: "service-01.jpg",
      sector: "Business",
      synopsis: "Completely synergize resource taxing relationships <strong>via premier niche markets</strong>. Professionally cultivate one-to-one customer service robust."
    }]
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="serviceListings[0].synopsis"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer works best. I have a div with the controller and I added the ng-bind-html to the <p> tag .. so <p ng-bind-html="serviceListings[0].synopsis">

Answer (score 1):

You can add it as a text and then use `ng-bind-html` in html to render it.

```
<element ng-bind-html="expression"></element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render the string as html like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="serviceListings[0].synopsis"></div>
```

You can also create a filter and sanitize the data using `$sce` if you want:

```
.filter('trustHtml', [
        '$sce',
        function($sce) {
            return function(value) {
                return $sce.trustAs('html', value);
            }
        }
    ]);
```

And to use it in the html file

```
<div ng-bind-html="serviceListings[0].synopsis | trustHtml"></div>
```