# HTML decoding in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, decode

We are using AngularJS version 1.5.6 and HTML characters are not displayed correctly in text. I've tried many codes but haven't been successful. There are a lot of associated topics in StackOverflow and I've tried most of them, but the HTML code structure still appears.

For example.

```
2 <sup>3</sup>
```

Displaying as. In more complex HTML codes, unfortunately, even the text is now difficult to read. How can I get HTML codes decoded?

core.js

```
app.controller('stockCheckAppController', function ($scope, $http) {
    stockCheckAppLoad(); 
    function stockCheckAppLoad() {
        $http.get("https://example.com/getSto").success(function (stockCheckAppData) {
            $scope.stockCheckAppLoad.innerHTML = stockCheckAppData;
        })
    }
});
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('stockCheckApp', []);
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('utils.autofocus', [])
        .directive('autofocus', ['$timeout',
            function ($timeout) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    link: function ($scope, $element) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $element[0].focus();
                        });
                    }
                };
            }
        ]);
})();
```

index.html

```
<h3 class="text-white">{{stockCheckAppData.name}}</h3>
```

Comment: You need to add `ng-bind-html-unsafe` to the h3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert HTML into view from AngularJS controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-from-angularjs-controller)

Comment: @csgabriella Sorry, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you injecting module `utils.autofocus` in module `stockCheckApp`.
If you are not aware then you can inject it like this:

```
var app = angular.module('stockCheckApp', ['utils.autofocus']);
```

I had this issues, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10971756/2008962 should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the reminder. But "utils.autofocus" was not working anyway. Do you have any idea for a solution with HTML tags?