# How to parse an html string and add it to the DOM in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I'm using a content service with an Angular app. Some of the API queries come back with strings wrapped in html tags ex. `"<p>Example value from API</p>"`.
I need to parse these strings and add them to the DOM as html elements.

If I save the API response to `question.body.value` then doing something like this:

```html
  <div *ngIf="question">
    {{ question.body.value }}
  </div>
```

Doesn't parse the html. Instead it just results in a `div` that looks like this (with the wrapping `<p>` tags printed to the screen):

```html
<div _ngcontent-iws-c79="" class="ng-star-inserted">
 "<p>Example value from API</p>"
</div>
```

What's the Angular way to parse these into html elements and add them to the DOM?
I've tried the Angular `Renderer2` and the native Javascript `DOMParser` but neither of these seem to be the right approach.

Comment: There are a couple options for how to do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-from-angularjs-controller/10971756#10971756

Comment: You can't paste html directly because it's not 'safe'.

Comment: <div *ngIf="question" [innerHtml]="question.body.value"></div> should work

Comment: Thank you @MikeOne [innerHtml] works.

Answer (score 0):

Via typescript:

```js
@ViewChild('elementRef') public elementRef: ElementRef;
public htmlString = '<b>Random string</b>';
public addHTML(): void {
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = htmlString;
}
```

Via html:

```html
<div #elementRef [innerHtml]="htmlString"></div>
```